# How can I identify an IC like this NXP microprocessor?

Tags: microcontroller, identification

[image]

The text on it says:

SC120541VLQ6
0N13E
QKE1544N

It seems to be an NXP microcontroller (because of the symbol of Freescale). So, I was suspecting it would be a MPC5606S, but I'm not sure: the connections don't seem to be consistent with the datasheet.

I don't know how to find it. Does anyone have a tip or an answer?

Comment: The pinout looks more like a [MPC5604](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/data_sheet/MPC5604BC.pdf)

Comment: Yes, I suppoused that it is a MPC5604C, I tried to read it with UPA, but I'm not having sucess. It seems not have TRST pin, so, I soldered the others, but communication failed anyway.

Comment: A custom chip like that has probably had it's JTAG readout ability disabled.

Comment: No guarantee it is a microprocessor. It could be a gate array etc with possibly a IP (Intelligent Property) processor created internally. Those could also be the end customers part number.

Answer (score 1):

It is a MPC5606BK, I read it in the document [AN4477 from NXP](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4477.pdf)!

Comment: It's really not clear how you came to that conclusion based on the linked AN. Notably, mask set 01N3E is not 0N13E, it appears to be a sloppy typo. The [actual errata](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/errata/MPC5606BK0N13E.pdf) uses the correct mask. I know NXP uses various weird, scarcely documented part number depending on if it is automotive qual or general/industrial.